# DLL load failed - not a valid Win32 application - with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I need to use numpy for python 3.2 (i'm using 3.2.5).

I've installed numpy 1.8.2 via the .msi for python 3.2, and i tried running some basic things :

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

print(x)
```

There's the console output :

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Askerad/PycharmProjects/untitled/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from numpy import *
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 n’est pas une application Win32 valide.
```

(the french part says : '%1 isn't a valid Win32 application')

i don't know what to do to make numpy work.

Edit : Changed the code just as Sarens said

Comment: You should write in the first line `import numpy as np` or delete `np` in front of `array`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an architecture mismatch, you need to install a [32bit binary](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) from that link as you are using a 32 bit version of python, I would  upgrade python to the latest [version 3.4](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) and use a 64 bit version of python then you can  install 64bit binaries. The latest version of numpy is also 1.9.2.

Comment: How could he even install numpy? Can you mix 32 and 64 bit CPython and Numpy installations?

Comment: @Trilarion, yes I have seen it happen before. You can install the 64 bit package but it won't work when you try to use it with a 32 bit python