# How to fix - Simple code generating OS Error - I am a beginner

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

My code is generating an OS Error. I'm using Python in a Jupyter notebook.

I've researched multiple questions involving similar issues, but haven't found anything that directly relates to this code.

```
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

> OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
>         2 
>         3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>         4 import numpy as np
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\inv_a_dataset\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py
>   in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line, _stack_depth)    2312
>   kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals    2313
>   with self.builtin_trap:
>   -> 2314                 result = fn(*args, **kwargs)    2315             return result    2316
>
> in matplotlib(self, line)
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\inv_a_dataset\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magic.py
>   in (f, *a, **k)
>       185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
>       186     def magic_deco(arg):
>   --> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
>       188 
>       189         if callable(arg):
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\inv_a_dataset\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\pylab.py
>   in matplotlib(self, line)
>        97             print("Available matplotlib backends: %s" % backends_list)
>        98         else:
>   ---> 99             gui, backend = self.shell.enable_matplotlib(args.gui.lower() if isinstance(args.gui,
>   str) else args.gui)
>       100             self._show_matplotlib_backend(args.gui, backend)
>       101
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\inv_a_dataset\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py
>   in enable_matplotlib(self, gui)    3400         """    3401
>   from IPython.core import pylabtools as pt
>   -> 3402         gui, backend = pt.find_gui_and_backend(gui, self.pylab_gui_select)    3403     3404         if gui != 'inline':
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\inv_a_dataset\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py
>   in find_gui_and_backend(gui, gui_select)
>       274     """
>       275 
>   --> 276     import matplotlib
>       277 
>       278     if gui and gui != 'auto':
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\inv_a_dataset\lib\site-packages\matplotlib__init__.py
>   in 
>       136 # cbook must import matplotlib only within function
>       137 # definitions, so it is safe to import from it here.
>   --> 138 from . import cbook, rcsetup
>       139 from matplotlib.cbook import (
>       140     MatplotlibDeprecationWarning, dedent, get_label, sanitize_sequence)
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\inv_a_dataset\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook__init__.py
>   in 
>        29 from weakref import WeakMethod
>        30 
>   ---> 31 import numpy as np
>        32 
>        33 import matplotlib
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy__init__.py in
>   
>       138 
>       139     # Allow distributors to run custom init code
>   --> 140     from . import _distributor_init
>       141 
>       142     from . import core
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy_distributor_init.py
>   in 
>        24                 # NOTE: would it change behavior to load ALL
>        25                 # DLLs at this path vs. the name restriction?
>   ---> 26                 WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
>        27                 DLL_filenames.append(filename)
>        28     if len(DLL_filenames) > 1:
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\inv_a_dataset\lib\ctypes__init__.py in
>   **init**(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
>       362 
>       363         if handle is None:
>   --> 364             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
>       365         else:
>       366             self._handle = handle
>
> OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
>
> > c:\users\rober\anaconda3\envs\inv_a_dataset\lib\ctypes__init__.py(364)**init**()
> >         362 
> >         363         if handle is None:
> >     --> 364             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
> >         365         else:
> >         366             self._handle = handle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DLL load failed - not a valid Win32 application - with NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324602/dll-load-failed-not-a-valid-win32-application-with-numpy)

Answer (score 1):

To fix:

- I uninstalled pandas and numpy using 'conda uninstall'.
- I uninstalled pandas and numpy using 'pip uninstall'.
- I installed utilizing 'pip install'

This was all from the Anaconda Prompt Terminal.

This fixed the problem.